# What instantiates the object when a parameter type of Action<SomeObject>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was looking through the .net core 2.0 code on github to unobfuscate some code in an article and came across [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/bc86ea4e47716e2b0bf0ceccc23e625d921098c7/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/DependencyInjection/MvcRazorPagesMvcBuilderExtensions.cs):

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddRazorPagesOptions(
        this IMvcBuilder builder,
        Action<RazorPagesOptions> setupAction)
{ }
```

On review, it didn't appear that an object of type `RazorPagesOptions` is ever explicitly instantiated. The question that I had was then how is the object of type `RazorPageOptions` instantiated?

Comment: That code just passes the action to `builder.Services.Configure(setupAction)`, so presumably that either creates the options or passes it to something *else* that does.

Comment: (Fundamentally though, you need to decide whether you're question is a *general* one as per your title, or whether you're interested in the Razor/ASP.NET Core-specific question about `RazorPagesOptions`.)

Comment: It's a general question. From what I can tell the object is being instantiated for me. I ran a seperate test trying this approach in a console application, didn't create an instance of the object, and use a non static method and it worked fine. Some how an instance of the object seems to be created for me using this approach.

Comment: The question is do I automatically get an instance of the object when I use it as part of a parameter that is a delegate without a return type

Comment: No, nothing creates an instance automatically. It sounds like this would be a more answerable question if you edited it to include your console app with details of what aspect you don't understand about it, and removed the Razor Pages part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to ASP.NET Core implementation of dependency-injection pattern. What Daisy pointed out in comments shows exactly that:

```
builder.Services.Configure(setupAction)
```

The `builder` is `IMvcBuilder`. `builder.Services` is `IServiceCollection` and that is, letssay, the master list of all services that are set up to be available in your asp-net application. Got FoobarService setup in Startup.cs? Then **definition** of IFoobarService will probably sit in the ServiceCollection. Etc.

The ServiceCollection has a ton of extension methods attached to it that make it easier to add new services. It has also `.BuildServiceProvider()` that takes all registered definitions and creates a service factory/provider/cache/resolver/thing that you/asp can later use to get actual instances of those services.

Then, aside from service registration and building the factory, because of the fact that "everyone is used to" set up things in Startup.cs where the ServiceCollection is in the spotlight, there's also a custom of configuring further details that a service may need right here in Startup.cs via even more extension methods on the ServiceCollection or sister objects.

Now, ASP.NET Core MVC has a module for handling application configuration. The design of it is such that you define a class, typically called WhateverOptions, that will contain some part of the configuration, related to Whatever, and that can be later retrieved by any service just by asking for it to be injected. However, since we split the configuration in to many more-or-less contextual objects, it'd be a huge mess if we were to instantiate them all (in one place?) and fill them up (in one place?!). For convenience all of them will be created by the framework. Remaining question is, who will fill them up with actual settings.

.. and this is close to what you have found. The line:

```
builder.Services.Configure(setupAction)
```

takes the Action (functor that takes 1 parameter: the Razor-Options) and registers it in the big-bag-of-all-infos-on-any-service. It gets registered as a source of settings for RazorPagesOptions. As a side effect, the IoC container also learns that there is a thing `RazorPagesOptions` that may be needed by some service(s).

Later, during the runtime, when someone asks for an instance of a service, if the service needs `RazorPagesOptions`, container checks if it was already prepared. If not, then an instance of those `RazorPagesOptions` is created (probably in singleton mode), but of course it's initially empty. Then, it is passed through all registered sources-of-settings. Each such source is invoked in turn, each of them gets that RazorPagesOptions instance, and each of them has a chance to fill it up with their part of settings. Finally, when all were ran, the instance of RazorPagesOptions (..is probably cached and then..) is passed to the service(s) requiring it.

One thing I didnt said yet is where did the instance of the `Action<RazorPagesOptions>` came. It came probably from Startup.cs. Somewhere there you'd have a line similar to:

```
services
    .AddMvc()  // registers MVC services in IoCC and gets you the IMvcBuilder
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
{
    options.RootDirectory = "....";
    options.Conventions.Add(new FooConvention....);
    ...
});
```

This `options => {..}` is the `Action<RazorPagesOptions>` that will be passed to AddRazorPagesOptions, and then to `serviceCollection.Configure` and that will be registered as the source-of-actual-settings for the RazorPagesOptions.

Takeaways:

- assuming you wrote an ASP.NET Core MVC app, then its your code in Startup.cs that created the instance of Action<> delegate - or actually "compiler did it" when you wrote a lambda when calling the AddRazorPagesOptions method
- this delegate is (probably) not invoked immediately, but is store for later use
- at some time in the application's runtime lifetime, the ASP.NET Core MVC framework will notice that RazorPagesOptions are needed and will create the instance. Probably via Reflection or Activator.CreateInstance(Type) so you won't find `new RazorPagesOptions()` anywhere
- all of that is specific to ASP.NET Core MVC, not pure C#
- similar mechanisms and patterns exist in other libraries/frameworks/IoCCs/etc
- and final note - I tried to write it in "easily understandable way", not to be 100% precise. Many things I wrote here are "a little bit not true", but IMHO, close enough

Comment: This is a beautiful explanation that completely cleared up a point of confusion for me. My apologies for not recognizing that this question really should have been tagged as asp.net mvc-core. Thank you both.

Comment: "ASP MVC" and "ASPMVCCORE" do not exist, please write proper names: ASP.NET Core is the only product being discussed here. Also, IoC is the pattern, what you are discussing is a container

Comment: I was referencing stack overflow tags, not products. To be more specific, what I was stating was that this question probably should have been tagged with  asp.net-core-mvc.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I've corrected all things you pointed out. However, you're a bit wrong: there's a ASP.NET Core as a general purpose platform/framework and there's a ASP.NET Core MVC - a plugin/module that provides MVC services, and it came into the scope of the text via `AddMvc()`+`IMvcBuilder`. What's a separate product and what's not is a disputable thing and depends on the layer you want to discuss it on. For marketing, sure, it's all ASP.NET Core. For other uses, separate assembly or nuget may be a separate product, and I see ASP.NET Core MVC as a separate thing built upon ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You said "ASP MVC Core" => it doesn't exist. ASP.NET MVC Core sure, that does exist. The entire DI framework, however, is on ASP.NET Core, not the MVC package, so MVC is not even relevant to this question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: How came you ignore the fact it passes through `this IMvcBuilder builder` which cames from `AddMvc()`? In what way you'd like it to be more relevant to MVC, when all the MVC services are build upon Core and its DI? You can take anything related to setting up the MVC and reduce it to "it's just DI" but that does not negate the fact it's relevant to MVC as well.

Comment: Crossed wires. You are referencing products. I don't disagree. What I am saying is that I agree with Daisy in that the question was specific to the framework and from that perspective deserved to be listed with that tag. Re-read the post and comments and it will help you understand.

Comment: @Bill: are you referring to Camilo's edit? I can revert that if you want

Comment: But, except for the tag change, all he did was improvement - better formatting, nicer link, etc

Comment: @quetzalcoatl This **is** a general DI question that's specific to the ASP.NET Core DI framework. The fact that the OP mentioned a MVC class has very little relevance. In fact, it would serve many more people if MVC wasn't mentioned, because I could give you hundreds of identical examples that don't require the MVC package to be installed.

Comment: You've fallen into some kind of survivor fallacy. There's a difference in the way you search when you know or suspect the answer and when you don't know. Your tag set promotes the former, original tag set promotes the latter.. I'll not argue anymore with your axiomatic'o'puristic need for correctness. Let it be your tag set, whatever. We've got enough Razor and MVC words for the google to pick it up.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, thank you again. Your answer was helpful and I appreciate the work you put into it. What you and daisy pointed out was that I simply did not understand the use of the services container and dependency injection.  This is a truth and I will endeavor to do more research on the topic and how it is implemented in other project types. Than you for your time.